# Как вывести количество совпадающих значений с одинаковыми индексами?

Tags: php

$arr1 = [10, 2, 4, 10, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$arr2 = [10, 2, 4, 10, 6, 6, 12, 0, 9, 10];

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
if($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$i]){
    echo $i."<br>";
}
```

Comment: А есть ли вариант с одним циклом?

Comment: Да. Значит просто счётчик нужно добавить и всё, в котором будет прибавление на 1 при совпадениях. Изначальное значение счетчика 0

Comment: Хорошо спасибо больше, буду пробовать.

Comment: К сожалению ни как не могу понять как его правильно добавить(

Comment: Добавляешь **переменную**-счётчик  **ДО** цикла с начальным значением 0. В цикле в условии вместо строчки с echo делаешь прибавление значения счётчика на 1. Всё. Дальше **После** цикла можешь вывести его значение

Comment: Спасибо большое.Все получилось.Искренне Благодарен)

Answer (score 2):

Как ни странно, но в пхп есть функции для вычислениях схождения массива (одинаковых элементов) в том числе, проверяющие совпадение не только значений, но и их индексов.

```
$result = count(array_intersect_assoc($arr1, $arr2));
```